# Python + Pandas + Dataframe : Keyerror

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have about 190 CSV's. each of which has same column names. A sample csv shared below:
[image]

From **every** csv, I need to pick **only** the `Item`, `Predicted_BelRd(D2)`, `Predicted_Ulsoor(D2)`, `Predicted_ChrchStrt(D2)`, `Predicted_BlrClub(D2)`, `Predicted_Indrangr(D1)`, `Predicted_Krmngl(D1)`, `Predicted_KrmnglBkry(D1)`, `Predicted_HSR(D1)` **columns** of **only** the **first row**, and need to store all these rows to a separate CSV. So the final CSV should 190 rows.

For that I wrote a code:

```
path = '/home/hp/products1'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
#print(all_files)

columns = ['Item', 'Predicted_BelRd(D2)', 'Predicted_Ulsoor(D2)', 'Predicted_ChrchStrt(D2)', 'Predicted_BlrClub(D2)', 'Predicted_Indrangr(D1)', 'Predicted_Krmngl(D1)', 'Predicted_KrmnglBkry(D1)', 'Predicted_HSR(D1)']
#columns = []
#df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:10, 15, 17, 50:100]]
rows_list = []
for filename in all_files:
    origin_data = pd.read_csv(filename)
    my_data = origin_data[columns]
    rows_list.append(my_data.head(1))

output = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
#output.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
output.to_csv('smallys_final.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

It gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-229c30dd03e1> in <module>()
      9 for filename in all_files:
     10     origin_data = pd.read_csv(filename)
---> 11     my_data = origin_data[columns]
     12     rows_list.append(my_data.head(1))
     13 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2131         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2132             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2133             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2134         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2135             return self._getitem_frame(key)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2175             return self._take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   2176         else:
-> 2177             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2178             return self._take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   2179 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1267                 if mask.any():
   1268                     raise KeyError('{mask} not in index'
-> 1269                                    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
   1270 
   1271                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: "['Predicted_BelRd(D2)' 'Predicted_Ulsoor(D2)' 'Predicted_ChrchStrt(D2)'\n 'Predicted_BlrClub(D2)' 'Predicted_Indrangr(D1)' 'Predicted_Krmngl(D1)'\n 'Predicted_KrmnglBkry(D1)' 'Predicted_HSR(D1)'] not in index"
```

Content of one of those dataframes:

```
prod = pd.read_csv('/home/hp/products1/' + 'prod[' + str(0) + '].csv', engine='python')
print(prod)
```

Output:

```
      Category                         Item  UOM  BelRd(D2)  Ulsoor(D2)  \
0  Food/Bakery  BAKING POWDER SPARSH (1KGS)  PKT          0           0   
1  Food/Bakery  BAKING POWDER SPARSH (1KGS)  PKT          0           0   
2  Food/Bakery  BAKING POWDER SPARSH (1KGS)  PKT          0           0   
3  Food/Bakery  BAKING POWDER SPARSH (1KGS)  PKT          0           0   
4  Food/Bakery  BAKING POWDER SPARSH (1KGS)  PKT          0           0   

   ChrchStrt(D2)  BlrClub(D2)  Indrangr(D1)  Krmngl(D1)  KrmnglBkry(D1)  \
0              0            0             0           0               1   
1              0            0             0           0               0   
2              0            0             0           0               0   
3              0            0             0           0               0   
4              0            0             0           0               1   

   HSR(D1)         date  Predicted_BelRd(D2)  Predicted_Ulsoor(D2)  \
0        0    10 FEB 19                  0.0                   0.0   
1        0    17 FEB 19                  NaN                   NaN   
2        0    24 FEB 19                  NaN                   NaN   
3        0   4 MARCH 19                  NaN                   NaN   
4        0  11 MARCH 19                  NaN                   NaN   

   Predicted_ChrchStrt(D2)  Predicted_BlrClub(D2)  Predicted_Indrangr(D1)  \
0                      0.0                    0.0                     0.0   
1                      NaN                    NaN                     NaN   
2                      NaN                    NaN                     NaN   
3                      NaN                    NaN                     NaN   
4                      NaN                    NaN                     NaN   

   Predicted_Krmngl(D1)  Predicted_KrmnglBkry(D1)  Predicted_HSR(D1)  
0                   0.0                       0.0                0.0  
1                   NaN                       NaN                NaN  
2                   NaN                       NaN                NaN  
3                   NaN                       NaN                NaN  
4                   NaN                       NaN                NaN
```

**Edit:**

```
prod = pd.read_csv('/home/hp/products1/' + 'prod[' + str(0) + '].csv', engine='python')
print(list(prod))
```

Output:

```
['Category', 'Item', 'UOM', 'BelRd(D2)', 'Ulsoor(D2)', 'ChrchStrt(D2)', 'BlrClub(D2)', 'Indrangr(D1)', 'Krmngl(D1)', 'KrmnglBkry(D1)', 'HSR(D1)', 'date', 'Predicted_BelRd(D2)', 'Predicted_Ulsoor(D2)', 'Predicted_ChrchStrt(D2)', 'Predicted_BlrClub(D2)', 'Predicted_Indrangr(D1)', 'Predicted_Krmngl(D1)', 'Predicted_KrmnglBkry(D1)', 'Predicted_HSR(D1)']
```

Comment: its seems your column names in CSV file have tab spaces

Comment: please can check first in one csv column names , type this print(list(data)) and check your column names are same as you are writing in columns

Comment: @Nickel check edit

Comment: @Nickel : any prob with index?

Comment: i don't have your data , its not possible to to tell you exact problem , mostly this problem occur due to column name not same

Comment: which data/table/file u wanna see, lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the tab spaces and re-excute the code. It may work fine. I think because of the unwanted tab spaces the dataframe is not able to distinguish the real values and outpus "KeyError".

Comment: Any problem with index?