# Error in panda (python) , 'KeyError: 'temp''?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to delete and check some data, which are in csv, and it gives problem at the same point every time I select a column.
If you want, you can see the file on this link https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak2pOptPmINYozaT9QYjjaZG7nqd.

In this link ([Python + Pandas + Dataframe : Keyerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411394/python-pandas-dataframe-keyerror)), what the problem is the same, several answers is about "remove the tab spaces", how so?

```py
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/teste/B116353.csv')
dataset.loc[dataset['temp']==-99999]
```

Every time I run the script, the following line exits:

```
KeyError: 'temp'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded the dataset. `KeyError: 'temp'` is returned because 'temp' cannot be found. Put a space before temp ( like this " tempt") because that is how it is in the dataset. The names didn't match.

Answer (score 1):

Doing with `str.strip`, then you should be able to get the output using `.loc`

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()
```